# How can I modify an installation module version based on the output of pip freeze

Tags: python, pip

Long story short, there was a script (written in python) that was written to automatically install a number of python libraries. I ran it with

`sudo python python_script.py`

And I got the warning

```
The directory '/home/dir/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

However when I checked the directories they are all owned by me. And when I do `pip freeze` I see nothing after running the installation script. So I ended up deciding to install the packages manually one by one.

When I do `pip3 install boto3==0.0.21`

I got an error:

`ERROR: botocore 1.0.0b3 has requirement jmespath==0.7.1, but you'll have jmespath 0.9.4 which is incompatible.`

when I do a pip freeze I get

```
alabaster==0.7.12
Babel==2.7.0
bcdoc==0.16.0
boto3==0.0.21
botocore==1.0.0b3
Django==1.8.2
docutils==0.15.2
futures==2.2.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
jmespath==0.9.4
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
psycopg2==2.7
Pygments==2.4.2
python-dateutil==2.8.0
pytz==2019.3
six==1.12.0
snowballstemmer==2.0.0
Sphinx==1.3.1
sphinx-rtd-theme==0.1.9
sphinxcontrib-httpdomain==1.3.1
```

How can I fix this error? Is there a way for me to change the `jmespath` from `0.9.4` to `0.7.1` to fix the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I don't think you should use `sudo`, unless you want to install under root. Try `python python_script.py`.

Secondly, try to uninstall the wrong version first, then reinstall the correct one.
Try

```
pip uninstall jmespath
pip uninstall jmespath
```

Do uninstall twice!

Then

```
pip install jmespath==0.7.1
```

Hope this helps